# How do you add jQuery code to the divi theme? That feature seems turned off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shared-libraries

Current site I am fixing: --> http://newmind.se/lagerbolag-2/

I want to make forms fieldsets generated by the Visual Form Builder separated in to a wizard or paged.

Where you can click your way through without leaving the page (there is a paged feature it seems but I want to learn jQuery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5wjRDnEg8s) but I want to trigger this on click of a button like a next button would make a certain div style.display:'block' and I figured the easiest way is was adding this functionality was through jQuery but jQuery seems turned off. Call to undefined variable from this piece of code I just added there to test if jQuery worked in the proper section in the Divi theme:

```
   //changing color on the headline on the page
   $( ".bengt" ).on( "click", function() {
     $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
   });

   //just putting a message in the console
   A $( document ).ready() block.
   $jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   });
```

Neither of these triggered within the divitheme even though jQuery library is included in the theme. Instead I got an error message Uncaught ReferenceError. Seems like the Divi-theme doesn't want me as a user to tamper with the jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

Remove $ sign from $jQuery and try this code, your Jquery library is loaded you are not calling it properly

```
   //just putting a message in the console
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

It seems like the divi theme weren't including the jquery properly when i added the link to googles version of jquery the jquery started working.. It seems strange as the divi wordpress theme is very proffesional in other ways. (http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/)

My friend told me about the document ready as well the jquery cant refer to something that is not loaded yet without the document ready function witch loads code when page is fully loaded. This was a free helpfull tutorial 2 on tutsplus.com: https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery